# Include PHP variables on AJAX page for SQL connection?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have one main file that is making a few ajax requests to update MySQL results, however the database it is connecting to changes based on a config in a subdirectory. ( /app/directory's index.php has `include: '../main.php'` as well as the appropriate SQL connection)

Using this for my ajax request:

```
<script>   $(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: <?php echo "'../fetch.php?year=$year&month=$month&date=$date'";?>,

            success: function(html) {
                $(".list").html(html);
           }

        });
    }, 5000); });

</script>
```

fetch.php is a copy of my sql query

This just returns an sql error because it isnt carrying over the database it should be connecting to, so its connecting to nothing. `data: {club:<?php echo $club;?>}` and then assigning `$club` to the appropriate database on the fetch.php file, but it seems to be breaking my ajax request (no error, it just doesnt poll).

How do i make an included page that uses ajax dependent on variables declared elsewhere?

Comment: So...... what exactly is your question?  You never actually asked one.

Comment: Post the error you got, beautify the code and check which is url parameter in this ajax request

Comment: How is it "breaking the AJAX request"?  What is the actual rendered JavaScript?

Comment: @crontab its sort of in the title, i'll add it again to the bottom!

Comment: Your question is **still** unclear. What isn't working, what do you need to work and how do you think it should work? Your code tells us nothing. Please, be more descriptive when it comes to the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i'm a moron. I added a variable in the URL (`&club=$club`) and then assign the database the ajax should connect to based on `$_GET['club']`

So easy yet i just couldnt think of it

Answer (score 1):

You are right, an Ajax call, just like any other request from the client, **does not get access to resources that were declared on a previous request**. HTTP is just a stateless mess like that...
(of course there are mechanisms to work around this problem, session, hidden fields, more arcane things like webworkers...)

If I understand you correctly, your DB connection is set up via index.php and main.php, but your ajax call directly requests fetch.php.
To have access to your DB connection, you need to inculde the according file in fetch.php, too (main.php?).

Btw, not having to deal with these issues is one of the main reasons to use a framework that offers a single entrance point and routing