# Jquery ajax call not working if using connection in include file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I can't figure out why jquery ajax post call not working if I used connection on include php file though I'm getting right response from php. Kindly tell me what's the explanation behind this

This is on my DB file

```
<?php

$host = "mysql2.000webhost.com"; 
$username = "a212_mt5199";
$password = "secret";
$db = "a211_mydb";

$con = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, $db);

GLOBAL $con;

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die ("Error:" . $con->connect_error);
}

?>
```

This **including the above** is not working

```
<?php

include("db.php");

// set parameters and execute
$myusername=$_POST['name']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['pwd']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM members WHERE username=? and password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $myusername, $mypassword);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=$stmt->num_rows;

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['user_name']= $username;
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

$stmt->close();
$con->close();

?>
```

This is working

```
<?php

$host = "mysql2.000webhost.com"; 
$username = "a212_mt5199";
$password = "secret";
$db = "a211_mydb";

$con = new mysqli ($host, $username, $password, $db);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die ("Error:" . $con->connect_error);
}

// set parameters and execute
$myusername=$_POST['name']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['pwd']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM members WHERE username=? and password=?");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $myusername, $mypassword);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
$stmt->store_result();

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=$stmt->num_rows;

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
    // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
    session_register("myusername");
    session_register("mypassword"); 
    echo 'true';
    $_SESSION['user_name']= $username;
} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

$stmt->close();
$con->close();

?>
```

Comment: Also with this one with no answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32665206/is-ajax-call-did-not-support-php-include

Comment: And this one with no clear answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17789118/include-php-variables-on-ajax-page-for-sql-connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Able to solve issue by using DEFINE variable.